How to get the model parameter for one vs rest SVC() using python?
I've tried to make a onvsrest classiffication model using decision_function_shape= ovr, but when i changed it to decision_function_shape= ovo, it gave me the same result as ovr. Turn out i read that svc() is using ovo as it base wheter it initiated as ovr or ovo. So how can i turn my code so it give me an ovr result?
model3 = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', decision_function_shape='ovr')
model3.fit(X_train, Y_train)
model3_predictions = model3.predict(X_test)

Ive tried using OneVsRestClassifier() but idk how to give the output of all of this one bellow, it always error and say OneVsRestClassifier dont have those commands. is there anyway to get the cm, sm, sv, beta, and intercept with OneVsRestClassifier?
cm3 = confusion_matrix(Y_test, model3_predictions, labels=[-1,0,1])
sm3 = classification_report(Y_test, model3_predictions)
support_vector3 = model3.support_
n_sv_model3 = model3.n_support_
alpha_model3 = pd.DataFrame(model3.dual_coef_)
b_model3 = pd.DataFrame(model3.intercept_)

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

OneVsRestClassifier has a .estimators_ attribute which lists all of the individual estimators (one per class). You can access each estimator one by one, and get its .n_support_ etc.
Regarding the ordering of .estimators_: My assumption is that .estimators_ will match the .classes_ attribute. So if you do ovr = OneVsRest(SVC()).fit(X, y), then I'd expect ovr.estimators_ to line up with ovr.classes_.

It only give me this output
[SVC(), SVC(), SVC()]

nvm i got it already, thankss. Btw i labeled my y with -1,0,1, do you know which list is for which, is .estimators_[0] for label -1, [1] for 0, and [2] for 1?

My assumption is that .estimators_ will match the .classes_ attribute. So if you do ovr = OneVsRest(SVC()).fit(X, y), then I'd expect ovr.estimators_ to line up with ovr.classes_.

I guess so, thanks, appreciate the answer
